# Doctrine SQLServer OneToMany leftjoin returning/mapping only one line, on production server only

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

Weird and annoying issue:

A simple Doctrine query with a leftJoin on OneToMany relation is returning (and mapping, to be more precise) only one line of the joined entities set, but only on the distant pre-production server.

I get the expected full result set on my local Wamp system.

The Database is in SQL server...

app/config/parameters.yml

```
 parameters:
     database_driver_class: Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
```

It's a simple OneToMany relation, as there are at least hundreds working fine in the rest of the application.

The generated SQL query works fine when called directly (returning the correct array).

The getArrayResult() method too.

As I don't even manipulate the data result behind, the only missing part is the Doctrine Mapping, which seems to behave differently on the servers.

I put the codes so you can see, but it is the simplest basic school example you can find in any tutorial or in the Symfony doc.

The problem is certainly coming from some config or mysterious system environment behaviour.

Help

Facture.php

```
/**
 * Facture
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="GAF_Facture")
 *    @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GA\FacturationBundle\Repository\FactureRepository")
 * @FactureAssert\Facture
 */
 class Facture {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GA\FacturationBundle\Entity\DetailFacture", mappedBy="facture", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"numLigne" = "ASC"})
 */
private $details;


/**
 * Get details
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getDetails()
{
    return $this->details;
}

/**
 * Set details
 *
 * @return Facture 
 */
public function setDetails($details)
{
    $this->details = $details;

    return $this;
}

public function __construct() {
    $this->details = new ArrayCollection();
}

}
```

DetailFacture.php

```
 /**
  * DetailFacture
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="GAF_DetailFacture")
  *    @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GA\FacturationBundle\Repository\DetailFactureRepository")
  */
 class DetailFacture
 {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GA\FacturationBundle\Entity\Facture", inversedBy="details")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="FactureId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $facture;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * Set facture
 *
 * @param \GA\FacturationBundle\Entity\Facture $facture
 * @return DetailFacture
 */
public function setFacture(\GA\FacturationBundle\Entity\Facture $facture)
{
    $this->facture = $facture;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get facture
 *
 * @return \GA\FacturationBundle\Entity\Facture 
 */
public function getFacture()
{
    return $this->facture;
}

}
```

The simplified code snippet I use to test in the controller:

AnyController.php

```
...

public function anyAction(){


    $dets = $this->em()->getRepository('GAFacturationBundle:Facture')
            ->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->where('f = :facture')
            ->leftJoin('f.details', 'd')
            ->addSelect('d')
            ->setParameter('facture', $facture)
            ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult()
            ->getDetails();

    foreach($dets as $d){
        echo $d->getId() .' -- cc -- ';
    }
    exit;

}
```

Displays:

On the server:

> 29 -- cc --

Local:

> 29 -- cc -- 30 -- cc -- 31 -- cc -- 32 -- cc --

Duuuuuude!! ! ! ! ! !!

EDIT: NEW CLUE
I reproduced the issue on another query (same page, different parameters..)
I made a modification in the addSelect method of the queryBuilder, after having compared it to others working: I added '[' to the addSelect:

```
 $qb
 ...
 ->addSelect(['ed', 'fr', ... ])
```

(instead of:
    ->addSelect('ed', 'fr, ... )
)

Kind of a random try..

But it worked!

Once.

Then coming back to a new instance of the page, the issue was there once again...

So I am now searching for some possible cache issue..

Comment: I'm going to ask the very obvious question, does your pre-prod server have a full set of data?

Comment: Same database.. Thanks for asking

Comment: As I wrote, the array result contains all the right data requested. Problem happens on Doctrine entity object hydration/conversion of the results.
Only on the server.

Comment: A direct SQL query returns all the lines too.